# Can I manually sync/refresh data from iCloud

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, xcode

I have a MacBook Air with the Xcode app that I use to add data to an array in one of the files.

The file is saved to the desktop.

I also have a MacBook Pro with the Xcode app that I use to add data and code throughout.

The file is also saved to the desktop.

I can't understand why or when the iCloud is syncing because sometimes I add the data to the MacBook Air and then when I open the file on the MacBook Pro I can see it update/refresh.

Sometimes I close the file on the MacBook Pro and open it up again so it can refresh the new data from iCloud.

The problem is that sometimes I can't do anything to update/sync/refresh the data to appear on the file on the MacBook Pro.

It changes from day to day and because I haven't been able to figure out why this happens, I want to know if there's a way to manually refresh the data from iCloud so it syncs to my MacBook Pro when I want it to.

Please advise if there's a way to do this.
Thanks ✌️

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in macOS which prevent data syncing over iCloud sometimes.

A workaround is to create a new file/folder under Desktop or Documents folder to *trigger* the sync. You can delete the temp file/folder immediately.

This is a *manual* hack to force a sync if the automated sync is failing.

Comment: Creating a new folder didn't always help but starting to send something via airdrop before cancelling it has so far been working.

Comment: Anyone have a 2023 update? Still seems to be a problem for me. Is this still the best "fix"? Specifically, I'm using Obsidian.MD and having trouble with synchronizing via iCloud.

Comment: @rinogo just tested it myself, been 24 hours since iCloud synced, I tried restarting my machine, didn't fix it. I created a file, and it forced a sync. this still works in macOS 13.1

Comment: I think you can also modify an existing file (seems to be working for me). @AO or someone else, can you confirm?

Comment: I like this solution the best because it's something I can easily do with a file manager and I don't have to toggle settings or wait for stuff to sync, etc, etc. I just create an empty folder, check the other device, YUP! It sync'd right away. Then I can just delete it afterwards. Simple and easy! Nice! Thanks a lot

Comment: This didn't work for me at all, no matter where I created a file. The only solution I found that works is now documented here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/465424/51852

Answer (score 6):

**Working solution in 10/2023**

Unfortunately, none of the existing answers worked on my side (M1 running macOS 13.6):

[image]

The only thing that actually does work is to invoke the following command in a terminal of your choice:

```bash
killall cloudd
```

The iCloud sync will then immediately start:

[image: sync working]

Comment: Worked on an Intel Mac running Ventura, too. Other approaches didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when saving/copying from one device and trying to access those files from a different device wouldn't show up/sync on iCloud when trying to access the file from other devices.

What finally worked for me is, whatever app/program/filemanager I used to save the file to iCloud I had to close the app so the computer doesn't think the file is still open. Since I have been doing that, I have no problem accessing files from my iPad/iMac/PC.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found for failure to sync to iCloud from a Mac is log out of the user account on the Mac, then back in. Works every time to refresh the contents of iCloud Drive

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do the following:

> Click on iCloud Drive in the sidebar of any Finder window.
> Open the file or hold down the Control key while clicking on the file, then select Download Now.
> Any changes you make to the file will automatically upload to iCloud Drive when you reconnect to the internet.

As per the online docs [here](https://support.apple.com/es-es/HT201104?cid=mc-ols-icloud-article_ht201104-macos_ui-02202023)

Answer (score 0):

On Ventura 13, you can force sync/refresh of **iCloud Drive** by restarting **Finder**.

- Go to * > Force Quit...*
- Select *Finder*
- Click *Relaunch*

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but ultimately doesn't work reliably (it did not on my side). Also, you might lose unsaved work (meaning that `fsync()` isn't called reliably anymore to flush buffers to the file system). An approach which has worked reliably for me is: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/465424/51852